# cloning laravel project (non-compound name 'App')

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm clonning my laravel project from my repo, then I run `composer install` and then `composer update`. But I'm getting an error:

> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> [ErrorException]                                                 The
>   use statement with non-compound name 'App' has no effect
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event
>   returned with an error
>    [RuntimeException]     Error Output:

I can't figure out why is this happening and google couldn't help me this time. This is the log, what more disturbs me is that I can `composer update` from another machine in which I pushed the firsts commits.

> [2015-12-15 18:41:42] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with
>   message 'The use statement with non-compound name 'App' has no effect'
>   in /var/www/html/anuncios.com/app/Http/routes.php:3 Stack trace:
>   0 /var/www/html/anuncios.com/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(41):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'The
>   use stateme...', '/var/www/html/a...', 3, Array)
>
> 1 /var/www/html/anuncios.com/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(41):
>   App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}()

...

Comment: Check in `storage/logs` for a `.log` file. It should contain deeper details on where the error is occurring. I suspect you have a `use App;` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much ceejayoz, that was the problem. What I don't understand is why `composer update` ran well in another machine with the same code.

Comment: Compare php.ini settings, especially the `error_reporting` setting between your development machine and whatever machine you are trying to clone your app on.